# Pass Named Parameter Conditionally

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, named-parameters

I have a struct which takes 3 named parameters in to the constructor...

```
public struct MyData
{
    private readonly double _value1;
    private readonly double _value2;
    private readonly double _value3;

    public MyData(
        double value1 = 1.0,
        double value2 = 2.0,
        double value3 = 3.0)
    {
        _value1 = value1;
        _value2 = value2;
        _value3 = value3;
    }
}
```

The method call that creates the class receives in three nullable doubles which I want to use to create the MyData class only if the nullable doubles are not null...

```
public MyData CreateMyData(double? value1, double? value2, double? value3)
{
    MyData myData;
    if (value1.HasValue)
    {
        if (value2.HasValue)
        {
            if (value3.HasValue)
            {
                myData = new MyData(value1, value2, value3); 
            }
            else
            {
                myData = new MyData(value1, value2); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (value3.HasValue)
            {
                myData = new MyData(value1, value3: value3); 
            }
            else
            {
                myData = new MyData(value1); 
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (value2.HasValue)
        {
            if (value3.HasValue)
            {
                myData = new MyData(value2: value2, value3: value3); 
            }
            else
            {
                myData = new MyData(value2: value2); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (value3.HasValue)
            {
                myData = new MyData(value3: value3); 
            }
            else
            {
                myData = new MyData(); 
            }
        }
    }
    return myData;
}
```

Is there a nicer way to write this method without modifying the MyData class?  I.e. **Can I conditionally pass named parameters or can I pass an indicator to represent the default named parameter value?**

Comment: Why don't you want to modify `MyData`?

Comment: In most situations I would, I just wondered if there was a way to do this without modifying MyData.  I ask this just in case I come across a situation where MyData isn't under my control (e.g. 3rd party library or something).

Comment: at least for now, most .Net libraries don't use optional parameters.

Comment: FYI, in your example since MyData is a `struct` not a `class`, it's important to note that `CreateMyData2(null,null,null)` will return MyData with `_value1`,`_value2`,`_value3` equal to zero. Structs have default constructors no matter what and will take precedence over the optional parameter constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public MyData(
    double? value1 = null,
    double? value2 = null,
    double? value3 = null)
{
    _value1 = value1 ?? 1.0;
    _value2 = value2 ?? 2.0;
    _value3 = value3 ?? 3.0;
}
```

This way, you can pass the `null`s directly and won't suffer from the [combinatorial explosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion).

Also, if you ever decide to change the defaults, it would work even without recompiling all users of this code.

Comment: He's asking for a solution that doesn't involve modifying `MyData`

Comment: @InBetween, ah, I didn't notice that.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer.  If I was creating classes for 3rd party use then, would this be a better way in general to design a class when using named value type parameters?

Comment: @Noob, if it was possible that you could change the default values in the future, then absolutely. If that was not the case, then yeah, probably.

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
   public  MyData CreateMyData(double? value1, double? value2, double? value3)
    {
        var ss= typeof(MyData).GetConstructor(new Type[]{typeof(double),typeof(double),typeof(double)});
        var parametesr = ss.GetParameters();
        return new MyData(value1 ?? Convert.ToDouble(parametesr[0].DefaultValue), value2 ?? Convert.ToDouble(parametesr[1].DefaultValue), value3 ?? Convert.ToDouble(parametesr[2].DefaultValue)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want just:

```
return new MyData(value1 ?? 1.0, value2 ?? 2.0, value3 ?? 3.0);
```

?

Comment: This way involves the calling method having control of the defaults.  I want the responsibility for the defaults to live with the MyData class.  This would mean that the defaults in the MyData class can be amended without having to find all references to the MyData class.  Thanks for the suggestion though :-)

Comment: Well, you can make `CreateMyData` a static method of `MyData` (if you are allowed to modify the class).

Comment: @noob: That reason doesn't make sense. Optional and default arguments are resolved at the call site not at the callee's. If you change the default arguments but don't recompile the consumer code together with `MyData` the consumer code will still call with the original defaults, not the new ones.

Comment: Ah right, that's interesting to know.  It would still be nice to have them just defined in the MyData class even if I still had to recompile all references.  Thanks very much for telling me about that though, that's something I didn't previously know.

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = typeof (MyData);
var c = t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(double), typeof(double), typeof(double)});
var p = c.GetParameters();
return new MyData(value1 ?? p[0].DefaultValue, value2 ?? p[1].DefaultValue, value3 ?? p[2].DefaultValue);
```

Comment: Yep, this is looking like the only alternative to modifying the MyData class or hard coding the defaults in the calling class.

Answer (score 0):

You need late-binding to do this. The open source framework [ImpromptuInterface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) gives you access to the DLR features needed to [dynamically pick named arguments](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#Named/Optional_Arguments).

```
using ImpromptuInterface;

...

public MyData CreateMyData(double? value1, double? value2, double? value3)
{
    var arg = InvokeArg.Create;
    var argList = new List<Object>();
    if(value1.HasValue)
        argList.Add(arg("value1",value1));
    if(value2.HasValue)
        argList.Add(arg("value2",value2));
    if(value3.HasValue)
        argList.Add(arg("value3",value3));

    return Impromptu.InvokeConstructor(typeof(MyData), argList.ToArray());
}
```